# How to embed code from Github repository like what you can do with a gist?

Tags: github, embed, code-snippets, gist

I would like to be able to embed code from files from my repository in my github pages.
I found this is working wonderful for gists but I do not find a way for a repository file.

Let's take an example :

- Here a file from my repository :

  - That I could use as permalink but will not work on my [post](https://dorian-gravier.com/2020/04/16/Batch-file-user-choice-reduce-quality.html) : https://github.com/DGrv/dorian.gravier.github.io/blob/508d48f21174fe693c127a7821aab7a2793de2fa/files/Batch/FFmpeg/FFMPEG_Bind_All_inFolder_v01.bat#L1-L35
- Here same on gists: https://gist.github.com/DGrv/771dd2b1f9c05d8fcf17f3ff84bfc1f3 using 
  `<script src="https://gist.github.com/DGrv/771dd2b1f9c05d8fcf17f3ff84bfc1f3.js"></script>`

  - you can find an example in [here at the middle of the page](https://dorian-gravier.com/2020/04/14/Export-Samsung-Notes-to-txt-jpg-Google-Keep.html) with the txt-to-google-keep-notes.py code

Does someone has a solution ?
Could be this an github enhancement ? or this does not make sense ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `.js` at the end of the gist URL, and including it in a `<script>` works very well

Proof with this code snippet (click "Run code snippet"):

```html
<div>
  Check out this source code:
  <br>
  <script src="https://gist.github.com/DGrv/771dd2b1f9c05d8fcf17f3ff84bfc1f3.js"></script>
</div>
```

However, that will only work with gists, and not Github files

Comment: Thanks. I could make this work as well but I wanted this with Github files actually.